# How to disable sorting for a specific columns in Ag-grid?

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I am using https://www.ag-grid.com/ in one of my AngularJs projects.My requirement is to disable the sorting on any column while any grouping is happening.

I know we can disable `sorting/filtering` on single column with below configuration:

```
colDef.suppressMenu = true
colDef.suppressSorting = true <--- this i can set up while giving column definition
```

but how to do it dynamically on the specific condition, For more clarification please check the image below
[image]

In this, I am grouping the grid by **country** and expanding **Ireland** country but now I don't to disable sorting on any parameter and enable it again when grouping attribute is removed.

Is there a way to achieve this, Please let me know and if any duplicate question already exists please add that in the comment section.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem :), adding answer so it might help others

> **Note:** I am not relying on Ag-Grid grouping I am getting after grouped data from my backend so below details can change for guys
>   depending on Ag-Grids only

Ag-Grid provides various event listener, one of which is `columnRowGroupChanged`

So I registered this listener :

```
vm.gridOptions.api.addEventListener("columnRowGroupChanged", vm.updateRowData);
```

Then in `updateRowData` method where i am creating my headerRow which will be used by Ag-Grid after grouping, I am also configuring at that time whether to sort or not :

```
vm.updateRowData = function (groupedColumnInfo) { 
                                /\
                                ||
                                ||
                           Column Information on which grouping has been done

............
............
 // Some Processing to get required details and finally setting the header again
............
............
vm.headerData = {
    headerName: groupingAttributeItem.label,
    field: fieldName,
    width: 150,
    headerClass: 'groupable-header',
    cellClass: 'groupable-cell p-xs',
    key: groupingAttributeItem.key,
    sort: (params.sortingInfo && params.sortingInfo.colId === groupingAttributeItem.key) ? params.sortingInfo.sort : '',
    suppressSorting: groupedColId ? true : false <--- deciding factor 
};

  // *Deciding factor* line checks that if some grouping has been done
 // if NO then don't suppress sort for that column otherwise enable sorting
}
```

**Note:** By default sorting is enabled on all columns so we have to explicitly disable it.

This is only the snippet of my complete code base, hence skipped how getting label and other things.

Hope it helps someone Thanks....

Answer (score 10):

the property for suppressing sorting is now

> sortable: false

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-sorting/

Answer (score 2):

```
colDef.suppressMenu = true
colDef.suppressSorting = true
```

http://www.angulargrid.com/angular-grid-column-definitions/index.php

Exemple: http://jsfiddle.net/7ony74h5/1/

Comment: Have you read my question's description complete?, I know how to set them while giving column definition. but my problem is different.
[https://jsfiddle.net/7ony74h5/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/7ony74h5/1/) This example is not working